# Get random expression generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, expression

I have a function that creates random integers but I am trying to refactor it to create random addition expressions instead. It's currently only still generating single integers. Then the consumer needs to log the sum of the random expressions that the producers are making. It's a work off of this old github. https://github.com/ajlopez/SimpleQueue/blob/master/samples/ProducerConsumer/app.js

```
var sq = require('../..');

function getRandomInteger(from, to) {
    return from + Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from));
}

function Producer(queue, name) {
    var n = 0;
    var self = this;

    this.process = function() {
        console.log(name + ' generates ' + n);
        var msg = n;
        n++;
        queue.putMessage(msg);
        setTimeout(self.process, getRandomInteger(500, 1000));
    }
}
//this should log 
//Producer generates 5 + 9
//Second Producer generates 12 + 8


 function Consumer(queue, name) {
    var n = 0;
    var self = this;

    this.process = function() {
        var msg = queue.getMessageSync();

        if (msg != null)
            console.log(name + ' process ' + msg);

        setTimeout(self.process, getRandomInteger(300, 600));
    }
}
//this should log the SUM of the 2 producers random expressions ie: 
//Consumer process 5 + 9 = 14
//Consumer process 12 + 8 = 20

var producer = new Producer(queue, 'Producer');
var producer2 = new Producer(queue, 'Second Producer');
var consumer = new Consumer(queue, 'Consumer');
```

Comment: `create random addition expressions` what do you mean by this

Comment: like 501 + 505, 515 + 549, ...

Comment: Those are just adding numbers together. I'm still as lost as before.

Comment: I guess you want to generate random math expression like: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195813/generating-random-math-expression

Comment: An example of the result you want to get?

Comment: yes gui4 but I don't understand how I can refactor my functions to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce a result as a string expression, whose numbers are between 500 and 1000:

```js
function rand(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomExpression(from, to){
  var a = rand(from, to), b = to - a;
  return a + " + " + b
}

var expr = getRandomExpression(500, 1000);

//

document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(expr);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your example!I think I can use some parts of it. I've updated my question again to better explain that a string wont work because the consumer needs to return the sum of the producers random addition expression

Comment: This actually gets me very close using parts of your code, thankyou. will select this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string like this 'X + Y' then add quotes so that js wont add the 2 random numbers

```
function getRandomExpression(from, to) {
    return from + ' + ' + Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from));
}
```

Comment: That wont work because I also need to create a consumer that can evaluate the random expressions, and return the sum

Comment: Then it is not clear what you need. please explain your case better cause this sounds like homework to me...

Comment: So, you'll have to get 4 random numbers, or are two numbers whose result is obtained another 2?